# JQuery Hide/Show textbox on checkbox select - works in Fiddle but not in live site

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a jQuery function, which hides and shows a form field when a checkbox is selected as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#unlistedUser").click(function () {
if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
    $('#unlistedCharacterName').show();
} else {
    $('#unlistedCharacterName').hide();
}
});
});
```

When this checkbox is selected:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="unlistedUser" id="unlistedUser" />
```

This text input field should appear and disappear:

```
<input type="text" name="unlistedCharacterName" id="unlistedCharacterName" placeholder="Unlisted Character Name" />
```

It works in Fiddle ([http://jsfiddle.net/jza7Z/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/jza7Z/))

But for the life of me I can't make it work in the site code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<title>Heroes and Heroines New Template</title>

<meta name="Description" content="Insert Description Here"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Insert Keywords Here"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="RPPDJPv5dTQ9yRcClT4OQvFw8UfoiikpHc7NMKZV1Ag=" />
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="26F28B51162242249219D0C4D1BAD146" />

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Heroes and Heroines News" href="/HandHRSS.xml" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/newMain.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/DatePicker.css" />
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/newMainIe.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/newMainIe876.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/unitpngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/admin.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/modules/events/events.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CC.js" language="JScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/AJAX.js" language="JScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmPost()
{
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if (agree)
return true ;
else
return false ;
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#role").change(function() {
if ($(this).val() == "Player") {
$("#CharacterName").show();
}else{
$("#CharacterName").hide();
} 
});
});
</script>
<script>
function confirmAction(){
var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
return confirmed;
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#unlistedUser").click(function () {
if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
    $('#unlistedCharacterName').show();
} else {
    $('#unlistedCharacterName').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">

            <div id="site_logo">
                <a href="/index.php">
                    <img src="/img/hand-of-good-symbol.png" alt="Heroes and Heroines Live Action Roleplaying (Larp)" 
                        title="Heroes and Heroines Live Action Roleplaying (Larp)" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="site_name">
                <p class="site_title">Heroes and Heroines</p>
                <p class="site_sub_title">Live Action Roleplaying</p>

            </div>

            <div id="info_box">
                <div id="nextEvent">
                    <a href="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php"><img src="/img/template/calendar-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>Next Event: <a href="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events/101_bring-him-home.html">11 - 13 July 2014</a>
                </div>
                <div id="galleryUpdate">
                    <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-photo-gallery.php"><img src="/img/template/gallery-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    5 New Images in the <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-photo-gallery.php">Gallery</a>
                </div>
                <div id="messageUpdate">
                    <!-- <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-message-system.php"><img src="/img/template/message-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    1 New <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-message-system.php">Message</a> -->
                    <a href="/new-forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox"><img src="/img/template/message-logo.png" alt="Private Messages" /></a>
0 New <a href="/new-forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox">Messages</a>

                </div>
                <div id="forumUpdate">
                    <!-- <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-forum.php"><img src="/img/template/forum-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    1 New <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-forum.php">Forum Post</a> -->
                    <a href="/new-forums/search.php?search_id=unreadposts"><img src="/img/template/forum-logo.png" alt="Forum Posts" /></a>
0 New <a href="/new-forums/search.php?search_id=unreadposts">Forum Posts</a>
                </div>
                <div id="newsUpdate">
                    <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-news.php"><img src="/img/template/news-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    1 New <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-news.php">News Item</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="character_selector">
            Logged in as sebsmith <br /><div class="linkButton"><form method="post" action="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/new-forums/ucp.php?mode=logout&amp;sid=c8a6b8f8ecae9a5736bd9a057c763521"><input type="submit" value="Logout" /></form></div><div class="linkButton"><form method="post" action="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/new-forums/ucp.php"><input type="submit" value="Control Panel" /></form></div>
            </div>


        </div> 

        <div id="body">

            <div id="main_menu_container">

                <div class="menu_bottom_bar"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="content_container">
                <HHTEMPLATE::siteMsg>
                <h1><span class="firstWord">Heroes</span> and Heroines Live Action Roleplay (Larp/LRP)</h1>
                <h2 id="siteSubHeader">A UK Live Roleplaying Group Based in The West Midlands</h2>

                <h2>Welcome to the Heroes and Heroines Event Booking Manager</h2>
 <h3>Make a booking for a friend for Bring him home (Fri 11 Jul - Sun 13 Jul 2014) </h3>
<div class="eventBookingForm">
 <div class="bookingFormDiv RefName">
<strong>Ref</strong>: Katie
 </div>
 <div class="bookingFormDiv Rank">
<strong>Rank</strong>: Low rank 5-26
 </div>
 <div class="bookingFormDiv Location">
<strong>Location</strong>: Consall Scout camp
 </div>
 <div class="bookingFormDiv Cost">
<strong>Cost</strong>: 
 </div>
 <h3>Booking Form</h3>
<p><form method="post" action="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=submitFriendBooking" class="bookingForm"><p><input type="checkbox" name="unlistedUser" id="unlistedUser" /> I am booking for a friend without a Heroes and Heroines User Account</p>
<label for="role">Booking:</label>
<select name="role" id="role">
<option value="Player">Play</option>
<option value="Monster">Monster</option>
<option value="MIA">Unable to Attend</option>
<option value="Referee">Referee</option>
</select><br />
<div id="CharacterName"><label for="characterName">Character Name:</label><select  name="CharacterName"><option value="122">Jack Dawkins</option><option value="197">Reverand Blighty Shrewson</option><option value="243">Sydion</option><option value="257">Englebert Waddicore-Critchley</option><option value="308">Brishen</option><option value="1015">yArp</option><option value="1017">NPC</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="unlistedCharacterName" id="unlistedCharacterName" placeholder="Unlisted Character Name" /></div>
<label for="bookingName">Attendee Name:</label><select name="bookingName">
<option value="112">3rd spearman</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="unlistedUserName" placeholder="Unlisted User Name" />
<div id="telephoneNumber"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number:</label>
<input required type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="01772 461406" /> <input type="tel" name="unlistedUserTelephone" placeholder="Unlisted User Telephone Number" /></div>
<div id="emailAddress"><label for="email">E-mail Address:</label>
<input required type="email" id="email" name="email" value="sebsmith@blueyonder.co.uk" /> <input type="email" name="unlistedUserEmail" placeholder="Unlisted User Email" /></div>
<div id="notes"><label for="notes">Notes:</label>
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="notes" /></textarea>
</div><input type="hidden" name="returnPage" value="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events/101_bring-him-home.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="dungeonid" value="101" /> <input type="hidden" name="unlistedUserBookerID" value="2"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit Booking" value="Submit Booking" />
<input type="submit" name="cancel Booking" value="Cancel Booking"></p>
</form>
</div><div class="clearDiv"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

            <div id="footer_menu_container">
                <div id="copyright_statement">
                    &copy; All content, images and design copyright Heroes and Heroines Live Roleplaying Club, 2012 unless otherwise specified
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried everything I can think of over the last couple of days, adding and removing elements, renaming elements, stripping down stuff until almost nothing remains, swearing, drinking and all to no avail. JQuery is far from my strong point. Can anybody see anything obvious which is preventing my script from running like it does in Fiddle?

Thanks!

Seb

Comment: What errors do you get in console?

Comment: Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:63
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:4
Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery.min.js:2
Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. jquery.min.js:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#unlistedUser").click(function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#unlistedCharacterName').show();
} else {
    $('#unlistedCharacterName').hide();
}
});
});
```

jQuery says that `prop` and `is` should return the same thing, but I feel more comfortable with `is`. Also, make sure that you are using a version of jQuery >= 1.8.3, as your fiddle works with that version.

change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: I modified the whole HTML with the scripts, here is the full source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<title>Heroes and Heroines New Template</title>

<meta name="Description" content="Insert Description Here"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Insert Keywords Here"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="verify-v1" content="RPPDJPv5dTQ9yRcClT4OQvFw8UfoiikpHc7NMKZV1Ag=" />
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="26F28B51162242249219D0C4D1BAD146" />

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Heroes and Heroines News" href="/HandHRSS.xml" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/newMain.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/DatePicker.css" />
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/newMainIe.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/newMainIe876.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/unitpngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/admin.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/modules/events/events.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CC.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/AJAX.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // short form for $(document).ready()
    $(function () {
        $("#role").change(function () {
            $('#unlistedCharacterName').css('display', ($(this).val() == "Player") ? 'inline' : 'none');
        });

        $("#unlistedUser").click(function () {
            $('#unlistedCharacterName').css('display', $(this).is(':checked') ? 'inline' : 'none');
        });
    });

    function confirmAction() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
    }

    function confirmPost() {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">

            <div id="site_logo">
                <a href="/index.php">
                    <img src="/img/hand-of-good-symbol.png" alt="Heroes and Heroines Live Action Roleplaying (Larp)" 
                        title="Heroes and Heroines Live Action Roleplaying (Larp)" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="site_name">
                <p class="site_title">Heroes and Heroines</p>
                <p class="site_sub_title">Live Action Roleplaying</p>

            </div>

            <div id="info_box">
                <div id="nextEvent">
                    <a href="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php"><img src="/img/template/calendar-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>Next Event: <a href="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events/101_bring-him-home.html">11 - 13 July 2014</a>
                </div>
                <div id="galleryUpdate">
                    <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-photo-gallery.php"><img src="/img/template/gallery-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    5 New Images in the <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-photo-gallery.php">Gallery</a>
                </div>
                <div id="messageUpdate">
                    <!-- <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-message-system.php"><img src="/img/template/message-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    1 New <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-message-system.php">Message</a> -->
                    <a href="/new-forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox"><img src="/img/template/message-logo.png" alt="Private Messages" /></a>
0 New <a href="/new-forums/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox">Messages</a>

                </div>
                <div id="forumUpdate">
                    <!-- <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-forum.php"><img src="/img/template/forum-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    1 New <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-forum.php">Forum Post</a> -->
                    <a href="/new-forums/search.php?search_id=unreadposts"><img src="/img/template/forum-logo.png" alt="Forum Posts" /></a>
0 New <a href="/new-forums/search.php?search_id=unreadposts">Forum Posts</a>
                </div>
                <div id="newsUpdate">
                    <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-news.php"><img src="/img/template/news-logo.png" alt="next event" /></a>
                    1 New <a href="/heroes-and-heroines-live-action-roleplaying-news.php">News Item</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="character_selector">
            Logged in as sebsmith <br /><div class="linkButton"><form method="post" action="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/new-forums/ucp.php?mode=logout&amp;sid=c8a6b8f8ecae9a5736bd9a057c763521"><input type="submit" value="Logout" /></form></div><div class="linkButton"><form method="post" action="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/new-forums/ucp.php"><input type="submit" value="Control Panel" /></form></div>
            </div>


        </div> 

        <div id="body">

            <div id="main_menu_container">

                <div class="menu_bottom_bar"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="content_container">
                <HHTEMPLATE::siteMsg>
                <h1><span class="firstWord">Heroes</span> and Heroines Live Action Roleplay (Larp/LRP)</h1>
                <h2 id="siteSubHeader">A UK Live Roleplaying Group Based in The West Midlands</h2>

                <h2>Welcome to the Heroes and Heroines Event Booking Manager</h2>
 <h3>Make a booking for a friend for Bring him home (Fri 11 Jul - Sun 13 Jul 2014) </h3>
<div class="eventBookingForm">
 <div class="bookingFormDiv RefName">
<strong>Ref</strong>: Katie
 </div>
 <div class="bookingFormDiv Rank">
<strong>Rank</strong>: Low rank 5-26
 </div>
 <div class="bookingFormDiv Location">
<strong>Location</strong>: Consall Scout camp
 </div>
 <div class="bookingFormDiv Cost">
<strong>Cost</strong>: 
 </div>
 <h3>Booking Form</h3>
<p><form method="post" action="/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events.php?task=submitFriendBooking" class="bookingForm"><p><input type="checkbox" name="unlistedUser" id="unlistedUser" /> I am booking for a friend without a Heroes and Heroines User Account</p>
<label for="role">Booking:</label>
<select name="role" id="role">
<option value="Player">Play</option>
<option value="Monster">Monster</option>
<option value="MIA">Unable to Attend</option>
<option value="Referee">Referee</option>
</select><br />
<div id="CharacterName"><label for="characterName">Character Name:</label><select  name="CharacterName"><option value="122">Jack Dawkins</option><option value="197">Reverand Blighty Shrewson</option><option value="243">Sydion</option><option value="257">Englebert Waddicore-Critchley</option><option value="308">Brishen</option><option value="1015">yArp</option><option value="1017">NPC</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="unlistedCharacterName" id="unlistedCharacterName" style="display: none;" placeholder="Unlisted Character Name" /></div>
<label for="bookingName">Attendee Name:</label><select name="bookingName">
<option value="112">3rd spearman</option>
</select> <input type="text" name="unlistedUserName" placeholder="Unlisted User Name" />
<div id="telephoneNumber"><label for="telephone">Telephone Number:</label>
<input required type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="01772 461406" /> <input type="tel" name="unlistedUserTelephone" placeholder="Unlisted User Telephone Number" /></div>
<div id="emailAddress"><label for="email">E-mail Address:</label>
<input required type="email" id="email" name="email" value="sebsmith@blueyonder.co.uk" /> <input type="email" name="unlistedUserEmail" placeholder="Unlisted User Email" /></div>
<div id="notes"><label for="notes">Notes:</label>
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="notes" /></textarea>
</div><input type="hidden" name="returnPage" value="http://www.heroesandheroines.org/heroes-and-heroines-larp-and-lrp-events/101_bring-him-home.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="dungeonid" value="101" /> <input type="hidden" name="unlistedUserBookerID" value="2"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit Booking" value="Submit Booking" />
<input type="submit" name="cancel Booking" value="Cancel Booking"></p>
</form>
</div><div class="clearDiv"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

            <div id="footer_menu_container">
                <div id="copyright_statement">
                    &copy; All content, images and design copyright Heroes and Heroines Live Roleplaying Club, 2012 unless otherwise specified
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also made the textbox originally hidden, but you can change that by deleting the style attribute: `style="display: none;"`

Comment: Thanks for your help, tried that just now but still no joy... :(

Comment: @The All Powerful Sorry to hear that.. could you please try the updated source? It works on Firefox, Chrome and IE for me.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! Your new code works perfectly! Thanks so much! :) So, If I'm looking at this correctly, the jQuery UI was causing the error? or was it in my jQuery script?

Comment: I do not think the jQuery UI was the problem. I believe it was your script not being correct/not up to date. The reason I believe so is that in JSFiddle, you did not put your jQuery script, but used the Fiddle's one and it worked perfectly. So, I would recommend to always stick to hosted libraries from Google or Microsoft. Since other users visit other website, they most likely have the jQuery cached already, and will not need to load it again, reducing traffic. Check this out: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Cheers!